# Where is OpenStreetMap download data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

The instructions for using OSM data in QGIS say, "Open QGIS and go to Vector -> OpenStreetMap -> Download Data…"
but, there is no OpenStreetMap in the Vector menu. Where do I find it, or, how do I get it? I thought it was supposed to be there automatically.

I am using QGIS 3.10.1 on a Mac running OS 10.14.6

Comment: do you have a link to the 'instructions'?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You'd better install a plugin, such as [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) that lets you chose features as well as a geographic extent.

Comment: You should check the documentation for 3.X, not QGIS 2. What is the extent or what do you want to download?

Answer (score 1):

Download based on extent go here: https://export.hotosm.org/en/v3/exports. Because perhaps, you don't need all data that sometimes can take large space.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.8.2 you can find Open Street Map in the "Web" menu => OpenLayers Plugin (just to display when working online).
The website to download the maps as shp files is  http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html. J
Just select the continent, country etc. and download as Zip file. CRS is WGS84 Lat Long.